# KOMA TOC: Changing tocline color

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft

Is it possible to change the color of the tocline (dotted line between entrys and page number) only? Im not sure if this is possible in KOMA and havent found out how to use tocloft for this (or if should even be done while using KOMA)

```
\documentclass[12pt, ngerman, bibtotoc, headings=standardclasses]

{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=.8mm]{default}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=.8mm]{default}{subsection}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
entryformat={\small\fontspec{SourceSansPro-SemiBold}}, 
pagenumberformat={\scriptsize\fontspec{Source Sans Pro}}
]{tocline}{section}

    \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
    entryformat={\small\fontspec{Source Sans Pro}}, 
    pagenumberformat={\scriptsize\fontspec{Source Sans Pro}}
     % linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
    ]{tocline}{subsection}
    
    % change the dotsep in TOC
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand*{\@dotsep}{2.}% default is 4.5
    \makeatother

        \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
        entryformat={\small\fontspec{Source Sans Pro}}, 
        pagenumberformat={\scriptsize\fontspec{Source Sans Pro}}
        ]{tocline}{subsubsection}


\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
entryformat={\fontspec{Source Sans Pro}}, 
pagenumberformat={\scriptsize\fontspec{Source Sans Pro}}
]{tocline}{figure, table}

(Lualatex)
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charter}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\newfontfamily\secfont[SizeFeatures={Size=20}]{Charter}
\newfontfamily{\Tables}{Source Sans Pro}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\scriptsize\fontspec{Source Sans Pro}}


\setkomafont{section}{\large\fontspec{Source Sans Pro Bold}}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\fontspec{Source Sans Pro Bold}}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\fontspec{Source Sans Pro SemiBold}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added a working example. Unlickily this method is not working and i couldnt find a method in the koma script. The only method that works is using tocloft \renewcommand{\cftdotfill}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\leaders\hbox to #1{.}\hfill}}. But the koma clases dont like this method.

Comment: Your example used font, I've not installed. And even if I replace all of them by fonts, that are part of TeX Live, it does not work without errors. So you first should solve these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed several code in your example, not related to the problem, fixed several mistakes like the error with the `(LuaLaTeX)` in the preamble. Then I've extended the code to a real working example. Finally I've added the `xcolor` package option `leaderfill={\TOCLineLeaderFill[\textcolor{Magenta}{.}]` to color the dots. See the Section 15.3 in the KOMA-Script manual for more information about the option `leaderfill` and the command `\TOCLineLeaderFill`. With the resulting example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,
  bibliography=totoc,% option bibtotoc is deprecated and should not be used
                     % any longer!
  headings=standardclasses]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}% Option ngerman above does not make much sense, without
                  % this package.
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=.8mm]{default}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=.8mm]{default}{subsection}

\newcommand*{\smallformat}[1]{\small #1}
\newcommand*{\textscriptsize}[1]{{\scriptsize #1}}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\smallformat,% The manual says: The value should be a command with exactly one argument.
  pagenumberformat=\textscriptsize,% The manual says: The command should expect exactly one argument, the page number.
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,figure,table}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
 linefill={\TOCLineLeaderFill[\textcolor{Magenta}{.}]}%
]{tocline}{subsection}
    
% change the dotsep in TOC
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@dotsep}{2.}% default is 4.5
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

As you can see here:

[image: snapshot from the table if contents with magenta dots for subsubsection entries]

is *does* work.

Comment: Thanks  @cabohah for your detailed answer. it helped me a lot.  Now everything is working fine and my koma preamble seems also a lot more clean. The problem was propably also caused by my twisted declaration of toc style entries.